# React-router server-side rendering on each page

Tags: express, reactjs, server-side, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to build an isomorphic app using express and react-router with data-fetching and first render server-side and data manipulation client side.

I managed to fetch initial data server side and render the jsx components but it works only if the url is directly hit, not following links. In fact, as in all the examples I've read, the app is server-rendered only once and then everything happen client side.

Plus, if I fetch some data, render a component server-side and then follow a link, the data are not updated for the new page.

I don't know if I'm trying to do something that makes no sense?

What I would like to obtain is:

- A pre-render server-side for **every** page, regardless of whether the user arrives directly or through a link
- Fetching just the **needed initial data the component corresponding to the route is asking for**
- [BONUS] apply **small changes to the layout regarding the component (title, additional css, etc.)**

Here is what I have so far:

Express app:

```js
var express = require('express');
require('node-jsx').install();
var React = require('react');  
var Router = require('react-router'); 
var routes = require('./routes');
var url  = require('url');
var resolveHash = require('when/keys').all;


var app = express();

/*
 ....
*/

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  Router.run(routes, url.parse(req.url).pathname, function(Handler, state){
      // create the promises hash
      var promises = state.routes.filter(function (route) {
        // gather up the handlers that have a static `fetchData` method
        return route.handler.fetchData;
      }).reduce(function (promises, route) {
        // reduce to a hash of `key:promise`
        promises = route.handler.fetchData(state.params);
        return promises;
      }, {});

      resolveHash(promises).then(function (data) {
        var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>' + React.renderToString(React.createFactory(Handler)({path:url.parse(req.url).pathname, initialData:safeStringify(data)}));
        res.send(html);
      });
    });

  // A utility function to safely escape JSON for embedding in a <script> tag
    function safeStringify(obj) {
      return JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/<\/script/g, '<\\/script').replace(/<!--/g, '<\\!--')
    }

});
```

routes.js:

```jsx
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");

var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var NotFoundRoute = Router.NotFoundRoute;

var Layout = require("./components/layout.jsx");
var Stuff = require("./components/stuff.jsx");
var Home = require("./components/home.jsx");

var routes = (  
  <Route path="/" handler={Layout}>
    <Route path="/stuff" handler={Stuff} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
  </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') { 
  var initialData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("initialData").innerHTML);
    Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
      React.render(<Handler initialData={initialData}/>, document);
    });
 }
```

layout.jsx:

```jsx
'use strict';  
var React = require('react');  
var Router = require('react-router');  
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;  
var Link = Router.Link;

var Layout = React.createClass({  
  render: function () {
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>{this.props.initialData.title}</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <nav>
            <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
            <Link to={'/stuff'}>Stuff</Link>
          </nav>
          <RouteHandler/>
          <script id='initialData' type="application/json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.props.initialData}}></script>
          // actually bundle.js is just made of routes.js as I put the client side render there
          <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
});


module.exports = Layout;
```

home.jsx:

```jsx
'use strict';  
var React = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({  

  statics: {
    fetchData: function(params){
      return {test:[1,2,3], title:'Home'};
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <section>
          <article>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Body</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <aside>
          Ads
        </aside>
      </div>
    );
  }
})

module.exports = Home;
```

stuff.jsx:

```jsx
'use strict';  
var React = require('react');

var Stuff = React.createClass({  

    statics: {
    fetchData: function(params){
      return {test:[4,5,6], title:'Stuff'};
    }
  },

  render: function(){
    return (<h1>Hello world from thingy!</h1>)
  }
})

module.exports = Stuff;
```

What are all the things I'm missing, misunderstanding, doing the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is intended to work, it will give you that first load and build that html and render it, after that it can't change that html that was generated unless you do a refresh of the page by clicking the refresh button or having your code `window.location`.

Comment: Is there a way to load the right initial data for each component before it's rendered?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't make a difference since it's going to be Javascript and it won't change what was printed to the browser.

Comment: you mean the only entry URL is the root URL?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. On the server, you should have your links mirrored in case someone visits one of your sub-pages directly. If you don't do that than the page won't render. So if you have http://.../about/ you should have a route that goes to that page from the server directly so that it can be served up right, otherwise it won't.